# Closure of numerical range contains spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A: D(A) \subset \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ be a densely defined operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with adjoint operator $A^{*}$. Given that $D(A) = D(A^{*})$ I'm trying to show that the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is a subset of the closure of the numerical range of A: $N(A)=\{ \langle x, Ax \rangle \vert \|x\| = 1, x \in D(A) \}$.

If $A$ is closed, I think we can argue as follows:
$ \| (z - A)x \| \geq \vert \langle x, (z-A)x \rangle \vert \geq \inf_{\|x\|=1} \vert z - \langle x, Ax \rangle\vert$.
So if $z \notin \overline{N(A)}$ we have that $(z - A)$ is injective und the inverse $(z - A)^{-1}$ is bounded on the range of $A$.

By contradiction Ran$(z-A) = \mathcal H$ and hence $z$ has to be in the resolvent set of $A$.

What I am not sure about is:

1. Is the above proof right?
2. If $A$ is not closed, does $\sigma(A) \subset \overline{N(A)}$ hold?

Can anyone help? 
Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Too long to be a comment.

Spectrum of a non-closed operator is not defined. If A is not closed, then $A−z, z\in\mathbb C$ is never closed and $(A−z)D(A)$ cannot be equal to $H$.

So far you have shown that $z\notin \overline{N(A)}$ implies that $(A-z)^{-1}$ is bounded on the range of $(z-A)$ which is closed. But the $Ran(z-A)$ need not to be the whole $H.$ You should probably use $D(A)=D(A^*).$

Can you prove it for bounded closed operators?

Comment: We defined the spectrum of a non-closed operator to be $\mathbb{C}$. So the question is: Is $N(A)$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @thomas.en: no. take e.g. $A$ essentially self-adjoint, nonclosed. Then $N(A)\subseteq\mathbb R$ which is not dense in $\mathbb C.$

Comment: In the bounded case: As above, $z \notin N(A)$, then there is $x$, $\|x\| = 1$ orthogonal to Ran$(z - A)$. But: $z - \langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle x, (z-A)x \rangle = 0$, which implies $z \in N(A)$, a contradiction. So Ran$(z - A) = \mathcal{H}$. What is wrong in the unbounded case?

Comment: @thomas.en. In the unbounded case, if you assume $x\perp Ran(A-z),$ it does not imply $0=\langle x,(A-z)x\rangle=z-\langle x,Ax\rangle$ because $x$ is not necessarily in $D(A).$

Comment: Thank you! I see… But until now I don't see how I can use $D(A)=D(A^{*})$ to get Ran$(z-A) = \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: I solved it! But I'm still unsatisfied with the non closed case. If $A$ is ess. self adjoint, it is symmetric and by assumption $D(A) =D(A^{*})$. Hence $A=A^{*}$ which is closed. So this is not a counterexample. Is it even possible to have a non closed operator with $D(A)=D(A^{*})$?

Comment: @thomas.en: could you post your solution? For the nonclosed case, I see that my example is wrong and I'm stuck with it))

Comment: $x \perp Ran(z-A)$ has to be in $D(A^{*}) = D(A)$, since $kerA^{*} = (RanA)^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ should be closed. Then, as you said,
$\| (\lambda-T)x \| \ge \langle (\lambda-T)x, \tfrac{ x }{\| x \| } \rangle \ge \| x \| \inf_{\|z\|=1} |\lambda - \langle Tz , z \rangle|$.
This amounts that $(\lambda-T)$ has closed image. But since the same inequality holds for $T^*$, and since  $\lambda-T^*$ is clearly injective, $\lambda-T$ has dense range. It is thus surjective. Now the inequality asserts that the resolvent in $\lambda$ is well defined, and bounded by $1/ \text{dist}(\lambda, \overline{N(T)})$.